# i need to insert some text from textarea and then update it in db as i type or save it using php ajax mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have this code to save note from text area

this is my post-note.php file

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['note_title'])){
    $note_title = $_POST['note_title'];
    $note_description = $_POST['note_description'];
    $login_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $errors = array();
    if($note_title == ""){
        $errors['note_title'] = 'fine';
    }else{
        $errors['note_title'] = 'fine';
    }
    if($note_description == ""){
        $errors['note_description'] = '<span class="note_description">Please enter something</span>';
    }elseif(strlen($note_description) < "3"){
        $errors['note_description'] = '<span class="note_description">your note is too short</span>';
    }else{
        $errors['note_description'] = 'fine';
    }
    if($errors['note_title'] && $errors['note_description'] == 'fine'){
        $Query = "INSERT INTO notes (note_title, login_user_id, note_description, is_private)
                                              VALUE('$note_title', '".$login_user_id."', '".$note_description."','0')";
        if (!mysql_query($Query)){
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $errors['done'] = 'done';
        unset($_POST['note_title']);
        unset($_POST['note_description']);
    }
}
echo json_encode($errors);die;
?>`
```

i want to insert first time as new row then want to update that row in database

Comment: to update a row you need to save an ID primary key to every row, so you can run update query where the ID equal to the row id

Answer (score 0):

In notes table, add a column id (if its not already there).
On create note page use above code.
On update note page pass id field of that note in $_POST.
So if `isset($_POST['id'])` write an `UPDATE note ... WHERE id=$_POST['id']`.
This will update already created note or will insert if its a new note.

filter user inputs before inserting though